# ambiguous iPhone crash report

Tags: iphone, crash-reports

I'm trying to decipher a crash report from an app in the app store; but it isn't very meaningful.

The crash file has been emailed to us, and we have tried symbolicating with the dSYM file from the original app build for the store; but none of the symbols resolve correctly; so we have reverted to using `atos` and running it over the binary submited to the app store along with the memory addresses in the crash file.

When we resolve the symbols using `atos`.

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 0x33b5c000 + 4712
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 0x33b5c000 + 13140
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a48648 0x33a20000 + 165448
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47ed2 0x33a20000 + 163538
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 0x33a20000 + 162944
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 0x33a20000 + 162696
6   GraphicsServices                0x33b0e4a4 0x33b0a000 + 17572
7   GraphicsServices                0x33b0e550 0x33b0a000 + 17744
8   UIKit                           0x32099322 0x32062000 + 226082
9   UIKit                           0x32096e8c 0x32062000 + 216716
10  MyApp                           0x00002b6c 0x1000 + 7020
11  MyApp                           0x00002b20 0x1000 + 6944
```

After we run `atos` over the memory addresses: `0x00002b6c` & `0x00002b20`

```
atos -o MyApp -arch armv7 0x00002b6c 0x00002b20
```

and it resolves to the following:

```
main (in MyApp) (main.m:14)
start (in MyApp) + 32
```

What could cause an app to crash in start/main ? We don't know the use case here; and are unable to resolve the symbols further up the stack.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

---

**UPDATE:** I did manage to symbolicate.

```
Incident Identifier: xxx
CrashReporter Key:   yyy
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         MyApp [343]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/1DACD08C-ECFA-4B24-913A-65E8F594AF7F/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:      MyApp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-03-03 10:28:38.346 +1000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2.1 (8C148)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a48648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47ed2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   GraphicsServices                0x33b0e4a4 GSEventRunModal + 108
7   GraphicsServices                0x33b0e550 GSEventRun + 56
8   UIKit                           0x32099322 -[UIApplication _run] + 406
9   UIKit                           0x32096e8c UIApplicationMain + 664
10  MyApp                           0x00002b6c main (main.m:14)
11  MyApp                           0x00002b20 start + 32

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b89974 kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c33704 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 88
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c33174 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 96
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c32b98 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd724a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcf970 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a48648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47ed2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x304df124 RunWebThread(void*) + 332
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 _pthread_start + 242
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a48648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47ed2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   Foundation                      0x336465f6 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 206
7   Foundation                      0x33624192 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation                      0x3361d242 __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 _pthread_start + 242
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b8168c select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x33a7f662 __CFSocketManager + 582
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 _pthread_start + 242
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd3d94 __semwait_signal_nocancel + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd3944 nanosleep$NOCANCEL + 108
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba50 usleep$NOCANCEL + 36
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33be9d78 abort + 56
4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bdba20 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3347c594 _objc_terminate + 104
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bd9df2 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bd9e46 std::terminate() + 10
8   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bd9f16 __cxa_throw + 78
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3347b4c4 objc_exception_throw + 64
10  CoreFoundation                  0x33ac0304 __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler + 208
11  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33481486 objc_enumerationMutation + 18
12  MyApp                           0x00016a32 -[Library downloadImages] (Library.m:202)
13  Foundation                      0x33624192 -[NSThread main] + 38
14  Foundation                      0x3361d242 __NSThread__main__ + 966
15  libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 _pthread_start + 242
16  libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 thread_start + 0

Thread 6:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd79e0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd7364 _pthread_wqthread + 540
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcf970 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd79e0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd7364 _pthread_wqthread + 540
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcf970 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a48648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47ed2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   AudioToolbox                    0x316504ba GenericRunLoopThread::RunLoop() + 30
7   AudioToolbox                    0x31663306 TRunLoop<AQClient>::Entry(void*) + 90
8   AudioToolbox                    0x316501d2 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 138
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 _pthread_start + 242
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 thread_start + 0

Thread 9:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a48648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47ed2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   CFNetwork                       0x30cffb24 CFURLConnectionSendSynchronousRequest + 244
7   Foundation                      0x336c7cfc +[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:] + 76
8   Foundation                      0x33665952 -[NSData(NSData) initWithContentsOfURL:] + 134
9   Foundation                      0x33665b74 +[NSData(NSData) dataWithContentsOfURL:] + 24
10  MyApp                           0x0001448c -[Song retrieveImage] (Song.m:69)
11  MyApp                           0x00016a58 -[Library downloadImages] (Library.m:204)
12  Foundation                      0x33624192 -[NSThread main] + 38
13  Foundation                      0x3361d242 __NSThread__main__ + 966
14  libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 _pthread_start + 242
15  libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
r0: 0x10004005    r1: 0x07000006      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000c00
r4: 0x00001303    r5: 0xffffffff      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x2fdfecf4
r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x050fc098     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0xffffffff
ip: 0xffffffe1    sp: 0x2fdfecbc      lr: 0x33b5f35b      pc: 0x33b5d268
cpsr: 0x600f0010
```

Comment: Have you checked the stack trace from the other threads?

Comment: in the crash report it mentioned that it was Thread 0 that crashed
`Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Crashed Thread:  0`

Comment: looks like it could be the other threads that are crashing the app - its just that its executing in the main runloop when the thread dies.

Comment: Can you place the _whole_ symbolicated crashlog here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check some object released, which send message ? My English is not good, I give some example as following.

```
NSString *aReleasedStr = [[NSString stringWithString:@"test"] release]; //< released

int aIntVal = [aReleasedStr intValue];  ///< crash
```

I encountered such crash report before, when I send a message with a released object. Maybe you can check such cases.

Comment: as a safe guard against that, I always set the str to nil because then even if you accidentally send a message to the object, it won't crash.

Comment: It is a good habit. :) I see "mach_msg_trap " in your crash report, so I think you send a message to a released object. Maybe the object is an autoreleased object, or being released by another thread. A case I encounted is released by another thread and set it to nil, but in original thread it is not nil, so it crashes.