# crash report and rejected by Apple

Tags: iphone

I just got the rejection mail from Apple.
It said:

```
Incident Identifier: 7A448508-7683-4337-A77A-5C2D86C309AF
CrashReporter Key:   8ea760a18a779819e657d0ca754d7431a29c383a
Hardware Model:      iPod4,1
Process:        MyAppName [9421]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/19335E91-C3D2-4735-B8AB-79931117D191/Zodiac.app/Zodiac
Identifier:     MyAppName
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-04-08 15:43:41.641 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.1 (8G4)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32da8a1c 0x32d97000 + 72220
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x337453b4 0x33712000 + 209844
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3373dbf8 0x33712000 + 179192
3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31093a64 0x3104f000 + 281188
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3186b06c 0x31865000 + 24684
5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31091e36 0x3104f000 + 273974
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31091e8a 0x3104f000 + 274058
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31091f5a 0x3104f000 + 274266
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x31869c84 0x31865000 + 19588
9   CoreFoundation                  0x326f548a 0x32657000 + 648330
10  CoreFoundation                  0x326f54c4 0x32657000 + 648388
11  UIKit                           0x32c03a4c 0x329fa000 + 2136652
12  UIKit                           0x32c04e02 0x329fa000 + 2141698
13  UIKit                           0x32b7e5e2 0x329fa000 + 1590754
14  UIKit                           0x32b4bf9e 0x329fa000 + 1384350
15  UIKit                           0x32a30eb8 0x329fa000 + 224952
16 MyAppName                            0x00003b8e 0x1000 + 11150
17 MyAppName                            0x00004194 0x1000 + 12692
18  UIKit                           0x32b7d3c0 0x329fa000 + 1586112
19  UIKit                           0x32c0395c 0x329fa000 + 2136412
20  UIKit                           0x32c04e02 0x329fa000 + 2141698
21  UIKit                           0x32a2f4c6 0x329fa000 + 218310
22  UIKit                           0x32a29b02 0x329fa000 + 195330
23  UIKit                           0x329fe7d0 0x329fa000 + 18384
24  UIKit                           0x329fe20e 0x329fa000 + 16910
25  UIKit                           0x329fdc4c 0x329fa000 + 15436
26  GraphicsServices                0x30bdde70 0x30bd9000 + 20080
27  CoreFoundation                  0x326cca90 0x32657000 + 481936
28  CoreFoundation                  0x326ce838 0x32657000 + 489528
29  CoreFoundation                  0x326cf606 0x32657000 + 493062
30  CoreFoundation                  0x3265febc 0x32657000 + 36540
31  CoreFoundation                  0x3265fdc4 0x32657000 + 36292
32  UIKit                           0x32a28d42 0x329fa000 + 191810
33  UIKit                           0x32a26800 0x329fa000 + 182272
34 MyAppName                            0x00002d34 0x1000 + 7476
35 MyAppName                            0x00002cb4 0x1000 + 7348

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32da93ec 0x32d97000 + 74732
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x337466d8 0x33712000 + 214744
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33746bbc 0x33712000 + 215996

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32da9fbc 0x32d97000 + 77756
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3194f094 0x31949000 + 24724
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3195004a 0x31949000 + 28746
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x3194f60a 0x31949000 + 26122
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3374658a 0x33712000 + 214410
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33746bbc 0x33712000 + 215996

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32da6c00 0x32d97000 + 64512
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32da6758 0x32d97000 + 63320
2   CoreFoundation                  0x326cd2b8 0x32657000 + 484024
3   CoreFoundation                  0x326cf562 0x32657000 + 492898
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3265febc 0x32657000 + 36540
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3265fdc4 0x32657000 + 36292
6   WebCore                         0x338fc292 0x338f6000 + 25234
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3374530a 0x33712000 + 209674
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33746bb4 0x33712000 + 215988

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x3f1c848c    r5: 0x00000006      r6: 0x0016bf3c      r7: 0x2fdfde00
    r8: 0x3eca0964    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x0016bae0     r11: 0x32d05d97
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdfddf4      lr: 0x337453bb      pc: 0x32da8a1c
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -     0x6fff +Zodiac armv7  <579b1d25b6ba0b494ca2cd8bb4bed467> /var/mobile/Applications/19335E91-C3D2-4735-B8AB-79931117D191/Zodiac.app/Zodiac
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe25fff  dyld armv7  <8dbdf7bab30e355b81e7b2e333d5459b> /usr/lib/dyld
0x309b0000 - 0x309b2fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <d55f1553d14831a2a5435ae27ef75ef4> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x30b3e000 - 0x30b76fff  IOKit armv7  <80ae313ad69d3363935c88e51a11862d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x30b7d000 - 0x30b84fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <ab9777b39e8e3026ad64dc90323cad7e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x30b89000 - 0x30bc5fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <79d00adb09de3da991ed21f48f27adb4> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x30bcd000 - 0x30bd4fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <0a082e1d475432959ba93aa3dbf7fb31> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x30bd9000 - 0x30be5fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <c508734deb43352782433a290ff235bb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x3104f000 - 0x31099fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <b2cac408951c3f3c9ba3cf563e54ce81> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x3109a000 - 0x310d2fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <ccea634795153164a681f0f311f4461d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x31311000 - 0x31430fff  Foundation armv7  <09ff368178c5321c9715b9c8d491d53f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x31431000 - 0x31718fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <652c97e211553d4e84968a61f62a0ac5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x31748000 - 0x3174dfff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <8c35c090bc373cb181fc26b961b8dba5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x3174e000 - 0x3177dfff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <1d73b8a159363f96bb9c039655c5eae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x31865000 - 0x31929fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <f855251d90a53bdbb5d5a39fdbde6d9b> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x3192a000 - 0x3192afff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <f47c01d627853b328e088b3fdd08e87d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x3192b000 - 0x31948fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <48016be86e3f3cd9aeee1c6590e1ac6f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x31949000 - 0x31956fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <6c4eeb08757b365f8429ef6747f89ad3> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x31b05000 - 0x31b05fff  vecLib armv7  <0c60cd0a60f43d2791d36cb357d30e3c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x31b0b000 - 0x31b10fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <1eaf25ddd98e3a249bca536671c5819d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x31ccd000 - 0x31cd1fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <2c61a8f7e7bf32d890e957d768d769ce> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x31d36000 - 0x31d39fff  IOSurface armv7  <ad50e71624583d06b891344d832f9b08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x31d6f000 - 0x31d74fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <a19b1caf96c73568b14a1660f147ae2f> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x31dd7000 - 0x31dd8fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <39bf0f48bd8539169a77f8f61cdcd4c9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x31e10000 - 0x31e1bfff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <ac706bee36593dc683fd5a96a389d72e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x31f5a000 - 0x31f66fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <c68262667ac8397a949ce4e92dfec7db> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x322b4000 - 0x32363fff  QuartzCore armv7  <ef9632c9781f3101916b65e9faae1579> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x323ec000 - 0x32405fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <4825c3e392983aba947eca06555e4480> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x32406000 - 0x32409fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <0479a171c00d3f629d639713acb72b5b> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x3246f000 - 0x3247dfff  OpenGLES armv7  <f02d1c50f0f33991adb1a2caed02eb77> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x325b4000 - 0x32612fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <d3f7360687333cad987890c314ae0d6f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x32613000 - 0x3261cfff  CoreVideo armv7  <ea847e6dba2d36b1826b255c73b39539> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x32657000 - 0x3273cfff  CoreFoundation armv7  <4f643539f91f330790f112ea7150b3a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x327b4000 - 0x327b4fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <21415179ffa03f949fa8cc851c6c31c7> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x327fd000 - 0x328bcfff  CFNetwork armv7  <b09e0d53de9f3bc8bde494780f3cdd4f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x329c5000 - 0x329cafff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <f5ccc8234aea3ebd9a88bd37f0fa23ae> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x329cb000 - 0x329d8fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0a1e2bb78d5138419ecad8ba0fe42fdd> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x329fa000 - 0x32d87fff  UIKit armv7  <c271b78464d93cb7bf28c6e49df293ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x32d97000 - 0x32daefff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <29eb602b615b3c3b95722868100a2d1c> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x32daf000 - 0x32dcffff  PrintKit armv7  <e5a01ca9083a36afacc08611a398e2ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x32df0000 - 0x32e5ffff  ProofReader armv7  <6d843c6aecdd37ae84baa40af8ad7e65> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x32e69000 - 0x32e6dfff  libcache.dylib armv7  <36e96d0a7dda330281a43172d0ada49a> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x32e7d000 - 0x32eb4fff  Security armv7  <163414ba17df347ca76088015010e2c4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x32eb5000 - 0x32fcffff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <bada0c2725bb31a483d5adf9aaf1f8df> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x331a6000 - 0x332c7fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <54e27b8aa66c32b48ffeadadcc514331> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x33451000 - 0x335a5fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <6619c8c13f8d328e923e797fa8d0df23> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x335a6000 - 0x3363bfff  ImageIO armv7  <d520e3241d1130e8ac1375ee0f2c1095> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x3368f000 - 0x336c4fff  AddressBook armv7  <3f2071a77bc134cd82065eef90d4082f> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x33702000 - 0x33704fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <94b6d6c5d9883175af26764567528127> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x33712000 - 0x33793fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <caa1846ad2583d1b84c1a15c50c126a2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x337ac000 - 0x337c1fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <e92cfbb83f7b330db19181e797bb3f7b> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x337c2000 - 0x337c4fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <683f321680763e519d61541170ba2133> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x33851000 - 0x3388efff  CoreText armv7  <fb6a72faec2330c4b2cd33c2e9c59588> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x338f6000 - 0x33f01fff  WebCore armv7  <b25d7d87ebd235ecbceca611a063c73b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x33f02000 - 0x33fabfff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <5538d3f2c7d83b88b06168488fe6326b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x33fc2000 - 0x33fc6fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e1cbfe599c96369ca4bdb0dd99d3cd9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x34475000 - 0x344cafff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <0221caba81a235c5a896a835e2aac047> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x344cb000 - 0x3451cfff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <8a41cc6a6d9332308bc415d27577fd24> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x34782000 - 0x34833fff  WebKit armv7  <eb9a0d69c64b3127b2bffd71641add3b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x34850000 - 0x34855fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9d7198e91de9386a9e5ea43608a66a57> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x348ca000 - 0x349cefff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <f63386018d703534b766514e4bbbd1d8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x349d2000 - 0x349d3fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <ccc041df3de73eafb7a59e74cdb1702b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x349d6000 - 0x349d7fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <5f077c4d204d3cd7b04452c42d41f763> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x349dd000 - 0x34a1ffff  CoreAudio armv7  <d45e275525ef3c32b36e0f1020cad705> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x34b51000 - 0x34b57fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <14c89b7346433c1f8675f454531f6ca3> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x34b58000 - 0x34b9efff  CoreTelephony armv7  <4319daea186b3a22b148ca78000f11ce> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x34bd7000 - 0x34bd8fff  CoreSurface armv7  <7b83cd757da73e6e826693c29296d3fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x34bec000 - 0x34becfff  Accelerate armv7  <7d5ad465049136afaa1f0d89aac600bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x36791000 - 0x36793fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <a2631ac302f4310dae8367939e16b7c2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x367ae000 - 0x367edfff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <b5735b0f3dba32c087c5b58aa48ae592> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x3691f000 - 0x3691ffff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <68322643de8030978c862de530055bd9> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x36920000 - 0x36949fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <57fef84bdc17301d8bf53ba0fb967fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x36953000 - 0x36972fff  Bom armv7  <b178e3efb4d733c694bd5a55e57a314f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x3699d000 - 0x3699efff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <41a7b5e5d9983449ab33affed0f635ad> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x36d1e000 - 0x36e0bfff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <f4146ce07e3031ea8a81fa5516fd77d0> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x36f3a000 - 0x36f6dfff  AppSupport armv7  <0217468bd9f839229a47910b7816b3d5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
```

Is there any way help me to locate the problem where it happens?

Welcome any comment

Comment: Error originated in MyAppName application, they don't have the source to check what went wrong. If you are the author of the application, it's up to you to find what went wrong. Plus, without additional information there's nothing to comment on.

Comment: First thing you need to do is symbolicate your crash log. You can use the atos ("address to symbol") tool to convert these addresses back to their symbolic names.

Comment: Can you load this crashlog in Xcode or the Console application?  If your .dSYM file for this build of the application is somewhere that Spotlight can index, they should symbolicate this for you.  Without that, we're flying blind here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ambiguous iPhone crash report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175990/ambiguous-iphone-crash-report)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try taking help from `atos`....it will give you the exact location and the method name where the crash is. This crash log from the apple is in the binary form you have to take out the name of the method where the crash is produced.

Just playing with `atos`.

The correct syntax for you should be:

```
atos -arch armv6 -o MyAppName.app/MyAppName 0x00002cb4.
```

For more help please refer to already asked [ambiguous iPhone crash report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175990/ambiguous-iphone-crash-report) and The syntax is in message# 12 of **[this link](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/8826-rejected-cant-reproduce-crash-uitabbar-related.html)**.